# PPM Conversion Binary to ASCII - Unexplained quality loss

Tags: c, image, converters

I'm working on a converter to convert a PPM from P6 (Binary) to P3 (ASCII).
Since PPM is a raw format I thought I will not experience quality loss but for some unexplained reason this what occurs upon conversion:

**Original image:**
[image: PP6]

**Converted image:**
[image: PP3]

This is the algorithm I wrote for the job:

```
int convertP6toP3(char* fileName)
{
    FILE *src, *dest;
    char *outputFilename;
    char magicNumber[3];
    int height, width, depth;
    unsigned char red, green, blue;
    int i, j, widthCounter = 1;

    if (checkFileExists(fileName) == FALSE)
    {
        printf("- Given file does not exists!\n");
        return ERROR;
    }

    else
        src = fopen(fileName, "rb");

    // create output filename #MUST FREE ALLOCATED MEMORY#
    outputFilename = getOutputFilename(fileName, ".p3.ppm");
    // REMOVE + AFTER TESTING
    dest = fopen(outputFilename, "w+");

    // check that the input file is actually in P6 format
    fscanf(src, "%s", magicNumber);
    if (strcmp(magicNumber, "P6") != 0)
        return ERROR;
    fscanf(src, "\n%d %d\n%d\n", &width, &height, &depth);

    fprintf(dest, "P3\n");
    fprintf(dest, "#P3 converted from P6\n");
    fprintf(dest, "%d %d\n%d\n", width, height, depth);;
    for (i = 0; i < width*height; i++)
    {

        for (j = 0;  j < 3; j++)
        {
            fread(&red, 1, 1, src);
            fread(&green, 1, 1, src);
            fread(&blue, 1, 1, src);
        }

        for (j = 0;  j < 3; j++)
            fprintf(dest, "%d %d %d ", red, green, blue);

        if (widthCounter == width)
        {
            fprintf(dest, "\n");
            widthCounter = 1;
        }

        else
            widthCounter++;
    }

    free(outputFilename);
    fclose(src);
    fclose(dest);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Why am I experiencing this quality loss?

**Edit:** While opening the output file of a GIMP conversion with notepad I found out my converter has 3 times more samples (red green or blue values) than GIMP's.

Comment: Have you checked that the meta-data (width etc.) looks okay? How about the pixel data? Is there as many lines of output as expected?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, There must be since the data of a PPM is sorted pixel by pixel from left to right, isn't it?

Comment: Reading e.g. [this description](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) of the P6 format, each colour value can be one *or two* bytes depending on the maximum color value. Maybe you should check that?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, `Each pixel is a triplet of red, green, and blue samples, in that order. Each sample is represented in pure binary by either 1 or 2 bytes. If the Maxval is less than 256, it is 1 byte. Otherwise, it is 2 bytes. The most significant byte is first.` My depth is 255 and therefore each pixel is represented by 3 samples (RGB), 1 byte each. I'm clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `for (j = 0;  j < 3; j++)` loops are the root of the problem, they print each pixel three times which makes the image erroneous.

Answer (score 4):

@Quaker has most of it

"Both for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) loops are the source of the problem, they print each pixel three times which makes the image erroneous."

This explains the loss of quality.  3 pixels are read in the errant

```
for (j = 0;  j < 3; j++) { fread(&red, 1, 1, src); ...
```

The value of the first 2 pixels are discarded.  The 3rd pixel is written 3 times in

```
for (j = 0;  j < 3; j++) fprintf(dest, "%d %d %d ", red, green, blue);
```

The *size* issue "image erroneous" is likely something else.  The pictures provided (Original is jpeg) and the resultant pic (a png with transparency (alpha channel)) are not the ".ppm" of the code.  Likely the size issue is that the original .ppm file was saved as a .jpg and the resultant .ppm file was saved as .png.  .jpg, being a lossy format, simply thew out some data and was able to make a smaller file than the .png file, which retained everything.